# About Setting Up Visual Studio On Windows

Tags: visual-studio

I've just downloaded and installed Visual Studio Community from here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx (That is at left)

However, I guess I downloaded wrong platform. In fact, I had wanted to create c and c++ projects using Visual Studio but this platform doesn't have section to create.

At the same time, I want to deal with web programming, I think the platform that I downloaded new for Web programming. Can I add c/c++ programming this platform as update?

Comment: Visual Studio definitely supports your intended language. Multi-language support includes C#, Visual Basic, F#, C++, JavaScript, TypeScript, Python, and more. Visual Studio guides you as you write, debug, and test code — no matter what language you choose. Almost makes me want to switch to windows.....

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you did not select the **Visual C++** packages when you installed it.

You can change the packages by going to:
Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features -> Microsoft Visual Studio -> Right Click -> Modify.

That should fire up the package selection window again and let you install other packages you may need.